# Factor with comma and percentage to numeric

Tags: r, class, types, numeric

I have a column ("rates")which is a `factor` with several levels such as:

> 16 Levels: -0,186% -0,229% -0,326% ...

When I try to convert it to `numeric`, NAs are introduced and I can't figure out how to do it properly.

```
rates=as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", rates))
rates=as.numeric(sub("%", "e-2", rates))
```

I also tried the following, which was the answer to a similar question, but it does not work either.
    `rates=as.numeric(gsub("\\%", "", rates))`

Comment: Try `as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', '-0,186%'))` Vs `as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', '-0,186'))`. That percentage symbol (`%`) is producing the NA

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `parse_number`-function from the `readr`-package and specify that a comma is used as decimal mark:

```
library(readr)
parse_number(rates, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ','))
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] -0.186 -0.229 -0.326
> ```

---

Used data:

```
rates <- as.factor(c("-0,186%", "-0,229%", "-0,326%"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use gsub:

```
# Example vector
vec <- as.factor(c("-0,186%", "-0,229%", "-0,326%"))

# Convert vector to numeric
vec <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("%", "", as.character(vec))))
```

Comment: You can use `sub` instead of `gsub`

Comment: that's perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I assume the levels of your initial factor are chars. Then you need to do both replacements at the same time:

```
rates=as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("%", "e-2", rates)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why should it be used at the same time? Best regards

Comment: If you do only one of these operations, `as.numeric` will get blocked as the other character is invalid for it. Alternatively, you could first run two gsubs in separate lines and only add as.numeric in the second one, or in the third line below.