# How to convert factor data type to numeric data without changing it's value

Tags: r

I'm using R in Azure databricks in Standard DS3 V2 . I have a R data frame, train, which looks like

```
head(train,5)
Loc  Date        Consumption
Lon  2020-12-01    47%
Lon  2020-12-02    30%
Lon  2020-12-03    50%
Lon  2020-12-04    50%
Lon  2020-12-04    50%
```

But the consumption column is factor data type. I'm trying to convert consumption column to numeric data type. So I wrote following code

```
train$Consumption1=as.numeric(train[, 3])/100
```

Divided it by 100 as before divide it was not coming fractional
Now my data is looking like this

```
head(train,5)
Loc  Date        Consumption  Consumption1
Lon  2020-12-01    47%          0.44  
Lon  2020-12-02    30%          0.26
Lon  2020-12-03    50%          0.48
Lon  2020-12-04    50%          0.48 
Lon  2020-12-04    50%          0.48
```

Can you suggest me how to convert Consumption as numeric data without changing it's value?

Comment: What does `class(train$Consumption)` return? Is your data stored as a factor? Are you using a version of R that's older that 4.0?

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of this answer in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17435403/2372064

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate (assuming it's a factor) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005566/factor-with-comma-and-percentage-to-numeric

Comment: A more canonical duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information (doesn't address the "%" issue though). The "%" makes R think the value is not a number.